# To prove or disprove that language is regular

Tags: finite-automata, pumping-lemma

Suppose the language L = {w | w is an integer whose sum of digits is a multiple of 2}. I strongly feel like this is non-regular language, but how should I choose a string to apply the pumping lemma?

Comment: Remember that a language is regular iff it is in SPACE(O(1)).

Answer (score 3):

The language $L$ *is regular* as shown by the following "flip-flop" style minimal and deterministic automaton $\mathcal{A}$, the crux is that you need only two states (not an unbounded amount of memory) to check parity. $\mathcal{A} = \langle \{odd,even\}, \{0..9\}, even, \{even\}, \delta \rangle$ which transition function $\delta$ is defined by :

- $\delta(x,even) = even$ when $x\in \{0,2,4,6,8\}$
- $\delta(x,even) = odd$ when $x\in \{1,3,5,7,9\}$
- $\delta(x,odd) = even$ when $x\in \{1,3,5,7,9\}$
- $\delta(x,odd) = odd$ when $x\in \{0,2,4,6,8\}$

Comment: Why is it that the automaton would fail in the case you mentioned? Also, what do you mean by fail? I think I must be overlooking something.

Comment: The last sentence was added. I dont understand it either.

Comment: As far as I can see, the added sentence was wrong.  I deleted it. You should always feel free to undo edits to your own posts that you think are wrong.